i want why renovate bot schedule to run every month but its not happening
Below is my code for renovate bot for my git repo.
But i see my requirement.txt & requirement.txt.internal files packages raises a PR whenever it finds new version.
i want to achieve this scanning to be done on monthly base and raise PR on monthly scan. But currently with below code my PR are getting raised on frequent bases.
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "python": {
    "registryUrls": ["https://pypi.org/simple", "https://XXXXXX.com/repository/pypi/simple"]
  },
  "pip_requirements": {
    "fileMatch": ["^requirements.txt.internal$"],
    "ignorePaths": ["^requirements.txt$"]
  },
  "schedule": [ "before 3am on the first day of the month" ],
  "prConcurrentLimit": 100,
  "prHourlyLimit": 100,
  "docker": {
    "schedule": [
      "before 3am on the first day of the month"
    ]
  },
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchUpdateTypes": ["major", "minor", "patch", "digest"],
      "automerge": true
    }
  ]
}

i want to achieve this scanning to be done on monthly base and raise PR on monthly scan. But currently with below code my PR are getting raised on frequent bases.

How are you running Renovate? GitHub app? Something else?

Did you check the logs (enable them in DEBUG) for information that may explain why it runs when it should not? Did you try to use CRON Syntax instead?
